# Ag-grid - How to show selectAll option enterprise set filter for show/hide columns

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid enterprise's set filter which is showing as follows:

[Show/hide columns image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3rAJ.png)

Is it possible to also show a select all option in this to show / hide columns from the image shown?

Answer (score 0):

The 'set filter' as described on their [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-set-filtering/index.php) is for giving options to filter the column on rather than having the user type in the filter manually.

In your example you show the selection of which columns to show or not. What will be more helpful for you will be to look at the [Column Menu](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-menu/index.php) on their documentation.